# C: hacking the function call stack

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to make a program that will help me understand the structure
of the call stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bar(int c)
{
    printf("BAR\n");
    return 1;
}

int foo(int a)
{
    int* barADD = &a - 1;
    a = *barADD;
    int* mainADD = barADD;
    *barADD = (int)bar;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Before bar\n");
    foo(2);
    printf("After bar\n");
    return 1;
}
```

foo modifies it's stack frame return address, so that instead of returning to main it writes the address of bar to the "return address" part of the foo()'s stack. While in bar, the program should be in the main() stack frame, because bar() doesn't have a frame of its own and foo()'s ebp register returned to main. bar()'s "return 1" should try to return from main() and throw an exception. Problem is that this code works just fine and main() executes correctly, printing

```
Before bar
BAR
After bar
```

I don't understand how this works and not crashing on the return part.

Comment: Lately, there have been several questions similar to this. How code like this works, or not, depends very much on the exact details of how your particular compiler lays out the stack frame, and where the return address is stored, so a general answer is not possible. For example, this code seems to assume that a function pointer is the same size as an integer. Is that true for your environment? Are you on a 32-bit or a 64-bit computer?

Comment: Did you check the assembly output which the compiler generates? Depending on the optimization level, `foo()` might not even explicitly be called from `main()`, and `foo()` might be reduced to essentially `return 1;`

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy, 32-bit

Comment: According to the cdecl function calling convention, this is overwriting the return address not the ebp. How is the control going to main is not clear to me yet.

Comment: I think it would make sense to use the debugger (`gdb -q`) and look at the disassembly of each function `disassemble foo` etc. Using breakpoints you can investigate with `info register` where the actual registers eip, ebp etc. point to.

Comment: As Thomas mentioned earlier, but straight to the point: This has nothing to do with C, and everything to do with your system.

Comment: Which compiler (version), which optimization level …?